# How to create dummy image

Tags: image

**I have seen many themes or scripts in which people use dummy images in places of image as shown in here :-** 
[*Dummy Image*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjgfE.jpg)

and when i check its url , its like data:image/64 svg image something like this format , so how to create such images for our project?

I want offline method to get such images which can work offline aswell.

I searched alot for the solution but unable to find any solution for it so far , i got the php gd method but i wanted to know how it can be done as data:image method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try : [lorempixel](http://lorempixel.com) 
if you want a 500 x 500 image
`<img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500" />` 

you can even specify the theme like : 
`<img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/500/nature" />`

Comment: Yaa that is a handy thing and many websites offer this , but i want a method which can work offline aswell

Comment: Thankyou so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Base 64 svg seems to be some kind of format that optimizes your images. You can read about it here:

[Base64 - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

And you can use the following website to optimize your images with the Base64 encoding:

[b64.io](http://b64.io/)